# Are "Where can I find this?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question is asking where they can buy a specific recording:

[Mike Oldfield - Tubular Bells - John Peel version](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/94/mike-oldfield-tubular-bells-john-peel-version)

Is this on topic? I would think that this information can go out of date pretty easily as sites come on and offline and licensing for the recording changes.

Comment: I created [another question](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/227/47 "Were “Mrs.” and “Mustard/Parking ticket song” from Buffy ever released?") for this discussion. Not exactly about *where* to find it, but asking *if* it was released.

Comment: @unor See [this new question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/116/are-was-this-ever-released-questions-on-topic) in regards to whether or not that kind of question would be on-topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think if the question were about the *techniques* collectors employ to find difficult-to-locate works, then it would be a good fit for this site. But questions like *"does anyone know where I can buy {rare album}?"* are not likely going to work well here.

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR - No, they are off topic.

Being that the primary purpose of Stack Exchange sites is to create a long-term searchable repository of knowledge, and that answer to this kind of question will, of necessity, be ephemeral in nature, I would have to conclude that we should make all such questions off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't vote on this answer, see the new question instead**

**[Are "Was this ever released?" questions on-topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/are-was-this-ever-released-questions-on-topic)**

---

Related & not enough to split to a new meta question, perhaps.

[Were "Mrs." and "Mustard/Parking ticket song" from Buffy ever released?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/227/were-mrs-and-mustard-parking-ticket-song-from-buffy-ever-released)

It's not so much a "Where can I find?" as a "Does it even exist?"

I'd call up/downvotes to this answer sufficient for a quick consensus on whether it belongs here or not, after considering the other answers here.

Personally, I have no firm opinion, I'd quite easily go with the flow.

Comment: I've spun this [into a new question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/116/are-was-this-ever-released-questions-on-topic). I think it's an important question, and I don't want the voting and discussion to get lost in this thread.

Comment: Fair enough - I wasn't certain enough to post it as a fresh question, but i like what you've done to make it into one.

Comment: It might be wise if I delete this answer in a short while, to prevent voting on it in here rather than your breakout post.

Comment: I've put up a few signposts in comment threads to direct people to the new question, so I would agree. People should definitely be voting on the new question, not this answer.

Comment: for sure - this one's gone then, now you've read my reply.

Comment: On second thoughts, maybe wiser to just add a redirect to the top of this answer itself, as votes are still allowed on deleted answers.

Answer (score -4):

I would like to see general questions, such as

- "Where can I download uncompressed music online"
- "Where can I find
  archives of the 1972 Swedish singles charts by week"

as on-topic.

Comment: These kinds of questions would present the same problem with companies going in and out of business. Right now, someone could answer that Neil Young's Pono music store would be a good place to download uncompressed music, but is that still going to be around in 2 years?

Comment: There are other on-topic questions on the site whose answers might go out of date - e.g "shortest single" will go out of date if someone releases a shorter one... less likely maybe, but same principle.

Comment: I actually don't like those questions either, because I would classify them as "trivia," but I'm not bothering to argue against them, because they will almost certainly be deemed to be on-topic.