# Are "Was this ever released?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Related to [Are "Where can I find this?" questions on-topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/are-where-can-i-find-this-questions-on-topic), but not a duplicate.

It's been decided that questions asking where to buy a song or album are off-topic, but a related questions would be "Has this ever been released?" An example would be this question:

- [Were "Mrs." and "Mustard/Parking ticket song" from Buffy ever released?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/227/were-mrs-and-mustard-parking-ticket-song-from-buffy-ever-released)

It basically asks if two extra songs that weren't released on the original soundtrack are available anywhere.

Personally, I'm on the fence on this one. The example is actually a pretty good question, and it's understandable why the extra tracks may be available. On the other hand, it opens up the door to ***A LOT*** of questions like `Is there a live recording of Pantera playing Planet Caravan?`

Answer (score 6):

Yes this, should be on topic. Like you said, it's not a shopping question.

There is a difference between saying 'Where can I buy X?' and 'Was X ever released?'

From what I can tell, this will help future users as well, where a shopping question wouldn't.

Comment: I think the difference is pretty negligible.  "Yes" or "No" answers are plain bad content.  A complete answer like "Yes, it was released on BuyWeirdMP3s.com" is effectively identical to "You can buy it on BuyWeirdMP3s.com".

Comment: "Yes, it was released on BuyWeirdMP3s.com" is a pretty vague answer though, whereas something more like "Yes, it was released on the UK version of the soundtrack" could help the user go off and locate said release.