# Original Sheet music especially for rock and pop music genres

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it ok to ask for how to find original soundtracks of rock or pop music? For example, Lou Reed Perfect Day. This is fairly easy for classical music, in other music there is still scores but they are different, not only in terms of tonality but sheer notes.

Comment: "in other music there is still scores but they are different" Like different per artist? That's common, yes. Everyone artist can have it's own impression, it's own version.

Comment: That same thing is made in classical music either with performing his her interpretation on stage whatever, or via commentaries on sheet music if he she is a sheet music preparing person and some nuances between notes. But almost never with notes, with a single one. Even nuances are very commonly same. These are different things making one's own interpretation with one's own impression. The same thing is done via paraphrases, arrangements, variations on a theme etc. in classical music, but it is clearly stated, and the originals are accessible always for other's to depend on if they wish.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that a broad question asking how one can go about finding sheet music for rock / pop music *in general* can work.

However, asking to find the sheet music for specific songs sounds like either a [shopping recommendation](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/3955) or a [transcription request](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66/3955), both of which are considered off-topic as per current site policy.

A question about whether a certain sheet music exists [might be on-topic](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/116/3955) since it can potentially be answered with a clear yes / no, but that does not seem to be the kind of question you're focussed on.